# Change Foreground item of ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I want to change the `Foreground` of a item on a `ListView` of my UWP.
I am using:

```
int i_DeleteRow = ListView1.SelectedIndex;
var item = ListView1.Items[i_DeleteRow] as ListViewItem;

if (item != null)
{
    item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

But with this code `item` is always null.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromindex(v=vs.110).aspx). It returns a `DependencyObject` then you can cast it to `ListBoxItem` and use the `ListBoxItem`'s properties like `Foreground`:

```
ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)(ListView1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ListView1.SelectedIndex));
if (item != null)
{
    item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your help. I am getting:
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in UWP15.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
in ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)(ListView_Metrados_Body.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ListView_Metrados_Body.SelectedIndex));

Comment: @Julius You should select an item from your `ListView` then click and run this code.

Comment: Yes I am doing that. I have that in a button.

Comment: @Julius I'm pretty sure this code works fine because I compiled it before I post my answer. Probably you have some issue in somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check it.